# Is there a way to start Safari with the Web Inspector open?

Tags: safari, webkit

I have to close and reopen it for development purposes like 100 times a day and the extra time it takes to open the web inspector disable cache, clear cache, start debugging javascript, and occasionally clear local databases is getting to be tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an AppleScript I wrote that launches Safari Inspector.  You can export it as an executable application and have it sitting in your dock to get into Inspector with a single click.  You could also launch it in a build phase in Xcode to have it run when your app is sent to simulator.  Change "iPad Simulator" to "iPone Simulator" or connected device as needed.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            set frontmost to true
            click menu item 2 of menu 1 of menu item "iPad Simulator" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```